# PHP Accessing XML sibling tag's attribute

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm using xml file like this;

```
<m>
  <n>
     <name id="1">test</name>
     <id>10</id>
  </n>
  <n>
    ......
  </n>
</m>
```

want to search 10 then get sibling tag "name"'s id value.

I'm finding 10 like below , however ,dont know how to get sibling tag "name"'s id attribute value, is there any method for accessing sibling's attribute?

```
$test=$xml->xpath("//n['10']/::*");
```

How can I access this id ("`<name id="1">test</name>`") value?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find preceding sibling `name` element from `id` element as follow :

```
//id[.='10']/preceding-sibling::name
```

Alternatively, you can find `n` element where child `id` matches the criteria, and then return `name` element from such `n` :

```
//n[id='10']/name
```

*) Add `/@id` at the end of either XPath above if you meant to return `id` attribute instead of the entire `name` element.

Comment: If you do add the `/@id`, remember that SimpleXML's `xpath()` method *always* returns an array of objects, never strings. So the actual value of the attribute would be accessed as `(string)$test[0]`.